# How can I get a parameter from the URL in my components constructor using ActivatedRoute

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I currently do it like this in my constructor:

```
this.articleSlug = _route.url._value[1].path;
```

But TypeScript doesn't like it:

```
Property: "_value" does not exist on type Observable<Params>
```

Is there a cleaner way? I'm using Angular 4 with TypeScript and webpack.

This is for when I use:  _route: ActivatedRoute in my contructor.

Comment: Could you expand on *"doesnt like it"*?

Comment: I've added error above

Comment: I'm assuming that `_route` is of type ActivatedRoute? If so you can try: `this._route.queryParams.subscribe( params => { this.articleSlug = params['yourParameter'] || ''});`

Comment: Presumably you're using `ActivatedRoute`, where [`.url`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRoute-interface.html#!#url-anchor) is an observable you should *subscribe to*. Have a look at the routing part of the tutorial: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html

Comment: Yeah, _route: ActivatedRoute

Comment: @eminlala my route doesnt have params, im trying to get end part of url only

Comment: What is *"end part of url"*? What *is* the URL? Could you give an actual [mcve]?

Comment: @jonrsharpe my url would be like this: https://www.mywebsite/blog/slug

so this would look like: https://www.mywebsite/blog/welcome-to-my-blog

Comment: Then please [edit] the question to include that information; you have enough rep that I shouldn't have to ask for this. Also do you actually want to resolve this with an `ActivatedRoute`, rather than provide module-level routing from pages to components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subscribe on the route and then extract it with callback function.
Something like:

```
_route.url.subscribe(values: UrlSegment[] -> /* url segments are available in values array */)
// or if you need url parameters
_route.params.subscribe(params: Params -> console.log(params['paramName']));
```